# SQLAlchemy: load_only does not work with aliased inherited model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy: `load_only` does not work with aliased inherited model.
I'm using this query:

```py
EngineerAlias = aliased(Engineer)
q = (session.query(EngineerAlias)
    .options(Load(EngineerAlias).load_only('id', 'profile')))
print q.all()
```

I've received an exception:

```py
NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row 
                    for column '%(140249955138512 anon)s.employees__type'"
```

However, such query works well:

```py
session.query(Engineer)\
.options(Load(Engineer).load_only('id', 'profile'))\
.all()
```

I understand that the issue is related to inheritance discriminator, `_type`, and if I add it to `load_only` list, everything will work. But i'm pretty much don't want to do that, because it will be an ugly hack in my code (kind of *"if it is inherited model, then add "_type" as well to load_only list, else..."*).

**Can anybody propose a way how to make query via aliased derived model without adding discriminator to load_only list?**

Dataset:

```py
class Employee(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(1000))
    _type = Column(String(50))  # discriminator

    __mapper_args__ = {
            'polymorphic_on': _type,
            'polymorphic_identity': 'employee',
            }


class Engineer(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'engineers'

    id = Column(Integer,
            ForeignKey('employees.id'),
            primary_key=True,
            )
    profile = Column(String(1000))

    __mapper_args__ = {
            'polymorphic_identity': 'engineer',
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been reported and fixed in there: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3287/load-options-arent-looking-at-the